# How can a heavyweight checkout be changed to a lightweight checkout in Bazaar?

Tags: version-control, bazaar

I have a shared repository like so:

```
repo/
  mainline
  featureA
  featureB
```

I like to do all my development in one place, so I do something like

```
> cd /Development/workingArea
> bzr checkout featureA
...
> bzr commit -m "Worked on featureA"
> bzr switch featureB
```

Over time, I've modified my feature branches to be treeless branches, as I found I was never interacting with those working trees.

I would also like to change the checkout in /Development/workingArea so that it is a lightweight checkout, as if I had used the --lightweight option.  I can't find a command similar to the bzr remove-tree command that would remove the history from the checkout.

Can anyone tell me how to do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

bzr reconfigure command:

```
bzr reconfigure --lightweight
```

See http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/latest/en/user-reference/reconfigure-help.html

Comment: Thanks - I searched the documentation site, but didn't manage to find the reconfigure command myself.  That looks like it will be handy in other situations too.