# How can a lightweight checkout be changed to a heavyweight checkout in Bazaar?

Tags: version-control, bazaar

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835515/how-can-a-heavyweight-checkout-be-changed-to-a-lightweight-checkout-in-bazaar) question discusses changing a heavyweight Bazaar checkout into a lightweight one. How can I do the reverse -- change a lightweight Bazaar checkout into a heavyweight one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `bzr reconfigure --checkout` command, for example:

```
$ bzr info
Lightweight checkout (format: pack-0.92)
Location:
  light checkout root: .
        checkout root: /path/to/workdir
   checkout of branch: /path/to/repo

$ bzr reconfigure --checkout
$ bzr info
Checkout (format: unnamed)
Location:
       checkout root: .
  checkout of branch: /path/to/repo
```